# Grab http requests by lynx

Tags: logs, browser, http, lynx, w3m

I need to grab and debug all HTTP-requests and responds which I make from lynx or another text-based browser. How can I save all request URLs, redirects, headers and page sources for analyze and debug this information? I do not need JavaScript support. What tools are better for this purpose?

**Update**

To partially solve my problem, I used [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/) text-based browser.

I start w3m with `-reqlog` option and w3m save all headers, addresses history and cookies in `~/.w3m` directory.

For example:

```
$ w3m -reqlog https://google.com
```

Check `~/.w3m`:

```
$ ls ~/.w3m
cookie  history  request.log
```

In `~/.w3m/request.log` stored all headers.

How can I keep the body of the pages?

Comment: I think you mean "grab" here, not "grub", so I changed that.  Have a look at [wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark); it's easy enough to view the http headers and allows you to save a record you can latter re-examine.  You need to do a little setup to run it as a regular user by adding yourself to the `wireshark` group (and logging in again to make that effective).

Answer (score 3):

Lynx's `-trace` option logs the information requested by OP, along with much more.  That is written to `~/Lynx.trace`

Further reading:

- [lynx manual page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/lynx1.html)
- [Re: Better to sniff with lynx](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/index.pl?node_id=367048)
- [Lynx.trace example](https://gist.github.com/sio/867566)